# "Take turns" in Russian

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

How should one express the concept of "*take turns*" in Russian?

For example, *taking turns* using the bench press in the gym, or *taking turns* on the Xbox controller or iPad.

Comment: a side question: is it correct to say "using the bench press?"

Comment: At least in America and in some contexts, definitely. For example: "Someone's already using the bench press" or "We can all take turns using the bench press." But, "I'm going to bench today" sounds better than "I'm going to use the bench (press) today."

Comment: ok, thanks. I was under impression that "bench press" was an exercise (a press which you do on a bench), and the appliance was just "bench"

Comment: That's correct, although if the bench comes with a barbell and safety rack and is clearly designed for bench pressing, then the whole apparatus can be referred to as a bench press. So, "Someone's already using the squat rack" and "Someone's already using the pull-up bar",  but "Someone's already using the bench press". This might be colloquial, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's *по очереди*.

> Jim and Bob are taking turns playing with their mom's Xbox // Джим и Боб играют в мамин Xbox по очереди.

Answer (score 1):

To add something to (completely valid) @Quassnoi answer. Sometimes "поочерёдно" form is appropriate as well. Regarding your examples.

> Поочерёдно занимая скамейку для жима лёжа.
>
> Поочерёдно занимая iPad